# OnAthorization в web api вызывается несколько раз

Tags: .net, авторизация, asp.net-web-api, атрибуты

Добавил атрибут для авторизации со своей логикой. Класс атрибута наследуется от AthorizeAttribute. При выполнении запросов к api, срабатывание OnAuthorization происходит два раза. С чем этом может быть связано и можно ли это как нибудь пофиксить?

Никаких данных для нового атрибута ни в webconfig ни в startup не добавлял. Добавил ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute класс, который наследуется от AuthorizeAttribute. Переопределил OnAuthorization метод, добавил в него вызов base.OnAuthorization(context) и свою логику. Протестил, оставив просто base.OnAuthorization(context) все равно метод отрабатывает два раза. После того, как определил новый класс для атрибута, добавил данный аттрибут для контроллеров, которым требуется авторизация. После, при вызове методов api происходит первый прогон OnAuthorization, затем второй и только после этого управление передается контроллеру api (если успешная авторизация). Если в авторизации отказано, метод выполняется ровно 1 раз.

Comment: Покажите настройки аутентификации IIS

Comment: Где они находятся?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/IIRTGaEj43

Comment: оу, у меня такой штуки нет. Iis express

Comment: Провайдните больше инфы. Где применяете аттрибут,веб конфиг что-нибудь держит, связанное с аутентификацией, какое различие между первым и вторым вызовом и тд.

Comment: Вы уверены, что атрибут срабатывает дважды для одного и того же запроса,  а не для какого-нибудь ретрая со стороны клиента?

Comment: Да, выполняю один запрос, на сервере выполняются два вызова OnAuthorization(). Или, я же правильно понимаю, если точка останова срабатывает два раза за один запрос, это значит, что метод вызывается два раза?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено, добавил настройки для аттрибута

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
```